# Invoking multiple tasks

Tags: c#

I've a C# application in which I need to invoke four asynchronous tasks(which internally call a third-party webservice).
Each task returns a boolean value true/false depending upon success or failure.

I need to invoke another method say PostProcessing() once any of these 4 tasks return true.
For e.g. if #2 method call returns true, I need to abort processing and invoke PostProcessing() method.

If all tasks return false, I dont want to invoke PostProcessing().

What's the best way to implement this approach please?Is it Task.ContinueWith()??

Thanks.

Comment: `Task.WhenAny` immediately comes to mind but that doesn't take into account the "when one returns true" part, neither does it stop the other tasks. This *could* be an XY problem, can you describe the real-life problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What happens if all four return `false`?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity,I've now updated my question.Thanks.

Comment: Note to ping a user you use the @ syntax (ie @Vineetv)

Comment: Thanks @BradleyDotNET.Point noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx) for this - it becomes drop dead easy.

To start with I'll assume that the signatures of the methods you're working with are these:

```
public async Task<bool> WebService1()
public async Task<bool> WebService2()
public async Task<bool> WebService3()
public async Task<bool> WebService4()
public void PostProcessing()
```

Now you can set this use Rx like this:

```
var webservices = new Func<Task<bool>>[]
{
    WebService1, WebService2, WebService3, WebService4,
};

IObservable<bool> query =
    webservices
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(ws => Observable.FromAsync(ws))
        .Where(b => b == true)
        .Take(1);

IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(b => PostProcessing());
```

This nicely calls all four web asynchronous services (`Observable.FromAsync(ws)`) asynchronously `.ToObservable().SelectMany(...)` and then filters the result to only those that return `true` (`.Where(b => b == true)`). It finally only wants one result `.Take(1)`.

Then, if it does get one result - which must be `true` - it then calls `PostProcessing` when that occurs.

If you need to abort before any web service returns you can always call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Simple.

Comment: Very clever, makes me want to investigate the Reactive Framework more.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - Once you start using Rx you'll find you never want to touch TPL again... it's too restrictive. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity.Just to confirm...so using this approach, lets say all the 4 methods are running concurrently, and method #2 happens to return true, then the program wont care if other methods return true or false and will abort all those 3 methods processing?Would this understanding be correct please?Thanks again.

Comment: @Vineetv - You're almost 100%. 4 methods running concurrently - yes. Method #2 returns `true` then other methods ignored - yes. Will abort those three methods - no, it can't unless you use an overload that incorporates a cancellation token. However, when using Rx you often chain together a series of operators - which you can see an example of in my answer - and, even though an individual step doesn't cancel, the chain is thus stopping processing.

Comment: Ok.Thanks @Enigmativity .

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would probably use Reactive Extensions (like @Enigmativity) mentioned.  If you want to avoid using Reactive Extensions, though, then I think you could combine `Task.WhenAny` with a while loop.  If I were to go this route I would create a static method to keep things clean.  So something like this:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<Task<TResult>> WhenAnyWithPredicate<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>, bool> predicate, params Task<TResult>[] tasks)
    {
        if (tasks == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (tasks.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;    
        }

        // Make a safe copy (in case the original array is modified while we are awaiting).
        tasks = tasks.ToArray();

        // Await the first task.
        var result = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

        // Test the task and await the next task if necessary.
        while (tasks.Length > 0 && !predicate(result))
        {
            tasks = tasks.Where(x => x != result).ToArray();
            if (tasks.Length == 0)
            {
                result = null;
            }
            else
            {
                result = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
            }
        }

        // Return the result.
        return result;
    }
}
```

You would use it like this.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

// Start your four tasks.
var tasks = new Task<bool>[]
{
    CreateTask1WithCancellationToken(cts.Token),
    CreateTask2WithCancellationToken(cts.Token),
    CreateTask3WithCancellationToken(cts.Token),
    CreateTask4WithCancellationToken(cts.Token),
}

// Wait for the first task with a result of 'true' to complete.
var result = await TaskExtensions.WhenAnyWithPredicate(x => x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && x.Result, tasks);

// Cancel the remaining tasks (if any).
cts.Cancel();

// If you have a nonnull task then success!
if (result != null)
{
    PostProcessing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

// Start the tasks
var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>
{
    WebService(cancellationSource.Token),
    WebService(cancellationSource.Token),
    WebService(cancellationSource.Token),
    WebService(cancellationSource.Token)
};

// Wait until first task returns true
bool success = false;
while (!success && tasks.Any())
{
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    try
    {
        // It either completed or failed, try to get the result
        success = await completedTask;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ignore or log exception
    }
    tasks.Remove(completedTask);
}

// Cancel remaining tasks
cancellationSource.Cancel();

// Ensure all tasks have completed to avoid unobserved exceptions
if (tasks.Any())
{
    try
    {           
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ignore or log exception
    }
}

if (success)
{
    PostProcessing();
}
```

Not as fancy as Enigmativity's solution, but straightforward ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm on my cell phone so will be hard for me to write any code. But from my understanding cancellation token is what you want. Please have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx

You can then register a callback for the cancellation request where you invoke your method. Please have a look at the example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191554(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That can help, only if he is listening for the tokens. Doesn't solve detecting the first one to return true though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You could register a delegate with the cancellation token that will be called

Comment: That doesn't *sound* like it would work to me; I'd have to see the code (which obviously you can't provide yet)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Provided an example :)

Comment: I get that part, but you wouldn't be *cancelling* the one that returned true, right? How do you detect that a task *that returned true* has completed?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think we might have a different view on what he is trying to achieve. Might be that I've confused some part

Comment: @BradleyDotNET no worries, that's a risk you take when trying to post answers from your cellphone haha